# How can I prove that $Set^I≃Set/I$?

Tags: category-theory

I need help to prove this equivalence. Anyone can do an exhaustive explanation about this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Note that the objects of $\def\Set{\mathsf{Set}}\Set^I$ are tuples $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of sets $A_i \in \def\Ob{\mathord{\rm Ob}}\Ob(\Set)$. A morphism $f \colon (A_i) \to (B_i)$ in $\Set^I$ consists is a tuple $f = (f_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\Set$-morphims (=maps) $f_i \colon A_i \to B_i$.

An object of $\Set/I$ is a pair $(A, \pi_A)$, where $A\in \Ob(\Set)$ and $\pi_A \colon A \to I$, a $\Set/I$-morphism $f \colon (A, \pi_A)\to(B, \pi_B)$ is a $\Set$-map $f \colon A \to B$ such that $\pi_B = \pi_A \circ f$.

The idea of the equivalence is that the map $\pi_A \colon A \to I$ splits the set $A$ is fibers $A_i := \pi_A^{-1}[\{i\}]$ and hence constitutes a $\Set^I$-object.

To define the functors which establish the equivalence, we can do as follows: Given $(A_i) \in \Ob(\Set^I)$, we define $F((A_i)) =: (A, \pi_A) \in \Ob(\Set/I)$ by $A := \coprod_{i\in I} A_i \times \{i\}$, and $\pi_A(a, i) := i$ for $i \in I$, $a \in A_i$. For a morphism $(f_i) \colon (A_i)\to (B_i)$ we define 
$$ F(f)(a, i) := \bigl(f_i(a), i\bigr), \qquad a \in A_i, i \in I. $$
This is a functor $F \colon \Set^I \to \Set/I$.

The other way round, for an object $(A, \pi_A) \in \Ob(\Set/I)$, we define $G(A) \in \Ob(\Set^I)$ by $F(A)_i := \pi_A^{-1}[\{i\}]$, and for a morphism $f \colon (A, \pi_A) \to (B, \pi_B)$, we define $G(f)_i := f|_{A_i}$, $i \in I$. Note, that $G(f)_i \colon A_i \to B_i$, as $\pi_B^{-1}[\{i\}] = f^{-1}\bigl[\pi_A^{-1}[\{i\}]\bigr] \iff B_i = f^{-1}[A_i]$.
This gives a functor $G\colon \Set/I \to \Set^I$.

It remains to show that both $F\circ G \colon \Set/I \to \Set/I$ and $G \circ F \colon \Set^I \to \Set^I$ are isomorphic to the identity:
For a morphism $(f_i) \colon (A_i) \to (B_i)$, its image under $G \circ F$, is the morphism $(f_i \times \mathrm{id}_{\{i\}}) \colon A_i \times \{i\} \to B_i \times \{i\}$, and the obvious natural transformation is an isomorphism. For a morphism $f \colon (A, \pi_A) \to (B, \pi_B)$, its image under $F \circ G$ is the morphism 
$$ \coprod_{i \in I} \pi_A^{-1}[\{i\}]\times \{i\} \to \coprod_{i\in I} \pi_B^{-1}[\{i\}] \times \{i\} $$
which is $f$ in the first and the identity in the second component. Again, the obvious transformation is an isomorphism.